# Uptempo electronic song with synthetic hand claps and wordless male vocal sample

Tags: identify-this-song, electronic-music

I have this file on my computer that iv'e had for the longest time, and over time I believe the file got corrupted. I've asked on every website and even used sound recognition apps like SoundHound, but to no prevail. It appears that this song is completely hidden from all databases. Someone please identify this song for me iv'e looked for so long. Here's a link to the song I recorded on my desktop.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcDJZSmjmlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinctive vocal riff with the handclaps is sampled from Continent #6 [Afromerica](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-dtwySzcQc) which was also sampled by Kanye West in his hit song [POWER](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sp1mVNOB5tg).

Since you can also hear other elements from "POWER" in your track, I would venture it's an unauthorized instrumental remix of "POWER."